# Ubuntu freezing at live install screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I just finished installing Ubuntu onto my laptop, and I decided to do it on my desktop. I used the same USB I used on my laptop to install it onto my desktop. I boot it up, and get the main purple live screen with options like "Try without installing", "Installing" etc.

If I click on any button, it instantly freezes the installer, the only way I can get past this is choosing the other boot option from my boot menu which is has "(UEFI)" In parentheses before the option. The problem is, my windows installation if in 'Bios-compatibility mode' thus, I don't want to install Ubuntu under a UEFI setting.

I've searched around but I have yet to find to find a specific answer. Most of the problems with this issue I've seen usually involve hardware.

My hardware specs are as follows: Nvidia GeForce GTX 980TI, i7 4790K, 16gb RAM.

If anyone has any ideas on how to fix this please let me know.

Comment: Without further troubleshooting I would suggest the use of nomodeset during install and the first use until you install Nvidia proprietary drivers. The GTX980 is most likely poorly supported by the open-source driver and then freezes at one point or another. Nomodeset will prevent loading that driver. The caveat is you gonna have low resolution until you install the Nvidia drivers but otherwise the installation should run smoothly.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I do this but sadly it still freezes :(

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you trying to install? Your brand new hardware benefits from newer releases, 16.04 or 16.10. Do not try any other.

Comment: @CelticWarrior The current installation I'm trying is 16.04. You think I should try 16.10, or would it not matter?

Comment: It shouldn't make any significant difference but who knows? I would try 16.10. I previously mention 16.04 but actually I should've mentioned 16.04.1 because the original release had a few issues and still required additional Grub parameters for some Skylake family CPUs. And Legacy mode is not recommended for such new hardware but since you already installaed the other OS that way, we'll have to make the omelet with the eggs we have.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Well I'm using 16.04.1 if you want to be specific. Also, BIOS is legacy mode? How can that be when I have CSM set to turn legacy boot off?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47205/discussion-between-celticwarrior-and-matt-jones).

Comment: We came to no conclusion in private chat. If anyone else has any ideas please let me know.